# How to enable word-wrap for editor in Android Studio on MacOS

Tags: android-studio, word-wrap

Recently the Android Studio 3.5 updates and now Android Studio 3.6, the editor window does not wrap the text so some lines are long and go off the right of the screen.  I don't want to scroll left and right all the time, so would like the text to autowrap.  I've read many posts on the issue but nothings has solved it.
I've tried going to 
Preferences -> Editor -> General and enabling soft wraps there, but that hasn't helped.
[image: editor options]

I tried adding *.java to the soft wraps files but that didn't help.

The only thing that works is selecting  View -> Active Editor - Soft Wrap.  That formats the current editing window with auto wrap, but each time I open a new java file auto wrap is not enabled I would need to enable it again.  This is so frustrating and was never an issue before Android Studio 3.5.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and my solution should work for you. The delimiter in the soft-wrap file list is a semicolon, not a comma: change your comma to a semicolon.